# Cooperation MongoDB lazy loading with Jackson @JsonIgnore in SpringBoot Rest Controller

Tags: java, mongodb, orm, jackson, lazy-loading

I have written a `RestController` in my `SpringBoot` app. I am using a `MongoDB` as well. This is my entity:

```
public class LocationEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private UserEntity owner;

    private String description;

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<RoleEntity> roles;

    private Date date;

    public LocationEntity(String name, UserEntity owner, String description, List<RoleEntity> roles, Date date) {
         this.name = name;
         this.owner = owner;
         this.description = description;
         this.roles = roles;
         this.date = date;
    }
}
```

`RoleEntity` and `UserEntity` are entities from the same database as well.
My `RestController`'s methods return `ResponseEntity`, so by default `Jackson` is used  inside to serialize `Object` to `JSON`.
I would like to ask about *lazy loading* precisely. If I use `@JsonIgnore` from `Jackson` to ignore that field in serialization, will ORM not get *"lazy fields"* from database?

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORM will only fetch those lazy loaded fields when needed. That means if you instruct Jackson to ignore them (using `@JsonIgnore` annotation) during serialization, ORM will not fetch them.